# CSS problem - firefox 1px shift

Tags: css, firefox

I have little problem with Firefox [on this site](http://rk.menyhart.sk/produkty/).

There is 1px shift on the bar under the horizontal menu in Mozilla Firefox.

Do you have any idea why? Thanks a lot.

[Image to show problem, originally linked in comment by OP. http://grab.by/grabs/7c758b8cdefa10f656b30837593d63d2.png](http://grab.by/grabs/7c758b8cdefa10f656b30837593d63d2.png)

Comment: Something like this...

http://grab.by/grabs/7c758b8cdefa10f656b30837593d63d2.png

Comment: I hope you don't mind but I edited your post to bring your image in-line with the question.

Comment: thanks, i didn't have enough points to put image directly in the post (i'm new here...)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the source art. That split is actually at the overlap location of two separate images (wrapper.jpg and header.jpg). They likely have slightly different color values at that edge causing browser resampling to sometimes round up instead of down. Why was that image split out into two? Making it all one image should solve the problem.

Comment: Because there is different content under the menu on the homepage http://bit.ly/cYYwZG

Comment: I'm pretty sure your only option is to zoom wayyyy in on both source art pieces and make sure they're perfectly aligned in the originals. Also make sure you're using the same jpeg compression level on each.

Comment: thanks for your time, i solved it with javascript (not optimal solution but it works...)